# Wordpress : ACF image not showinhttp://stackexchange.com/g correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an issue trying to display an image. I use last ACF 
but not showing image 
when i take look in html  i get this :

```
<img src="2119, , , , , image/jpeg, /wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ef51d8e8f5cf684e7654f0ea4ab7ce33.jpg, 1024, 681, Array" alt="">
```

my name slug is hotes

```
  <span><img src="<?php the_field('hotes',256); ?>" alt="" /><span>
```

Answer (score 0):

the post meta for image is an array of data containing url, height, width etc.

based on the docs,
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/
you should be doing it like this,

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image_test'), 'full'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_the_title(get_field('image_test')) ?>" />
```

or this way,

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

or by using native `get_post_meta` function

```
$image = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'hotes'); // Get Image Object
$image_url = $image['url']; // Retrieve image url
```

Comment: check the image object ```echo '<pre>', print_r($image, 1), '</pre>';``` and see if it returns anything

Comment: looks like you just copy and pasted the code I provided without even changing the meta key, please take some time to read the ACF docs,